# Kendo UI: Render List of Widgets

Tags: kendo-ui

I am completely new to using Kendo UI, and would like some help on how to render a array of objects to the screen with each object having it's own data source.

**Application Background:** A SPA dashboard that will show a list of charts that a user can interact with, moving (drag and drop), deleting, creating new charts.

I have done some digging into the Kendo framework and haven't landed on a solution that seems to work. My original thought was to use a custom defined widget that would use a template to render the charts to the screen and each widget would have it's own data source. However, I couldn't figure out a way to render the widgets.

I tried the MVVM data-bind: source and using a Kendo template to load the widget with the data-role attribute, but that didn't work.

*HTML content area*

```
<div data-bind="source: widgetsDataSource" data-template="widget-template-test"></div>
```

*Kendo Template*

```
<script type="text/x-kendo-template" id="widget-template-test">
      <div data-role="custom-widget"></div>
</script>
```

*widgetsDataSource*: the dataSouce used to retrieve the list of charts to render to the screen

*widget-template-test*: the template used to initialize and show the custom widget using the data-role attribute

*custom-widget*: The link to the custom widget I defined in separate JS file.

**Question:** Does anyone have a resource I may look at or some suggestions on how to tackle this problem? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I do a lot of work with kendo widgets, my go to resources are the API docs http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/introduction and then if I want to see some demos http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/, I use them with Angular, the demo's are nice because they have Angular specific (as well as MVVM) code, the API docs are handy when you are looking for specific configuration settings.

Comment: Would you say that using a custom widget would be the best route to take? I also thought of use the View component of and passing in a model, but after looking into that it didn't make much since.

Comment: It sounds like a Grid with a details row implementation would get you pretty far, that is the "bread and butter" widget of kendo ui land IMO.

Comment: Hmm, looking at the Grid and it doesn't seem to fit what I need. For a better illustration of what I'm after picture this:

A handful of <divs> each only 200px by 200px laid out across the screen positioned absolutely by dragging a dropping them. Each <div> represents a chart defined by a user and has it's own dataset to render.

I'm still thinking a custom widget to handle this is the best way; however, placing those widgets on the screen is proving difficult for me.

Comment: On a second look, it seems that all the data-role attributes are not firing off the widgets in Kendo.

Is there some restriction to the widgets that does not allow them to be instantiated via HTML?

Comment: @InvaderZim Have you gone through http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/intro/widget-basics/create-custom-kendo-widget ?

Comment: I have, and I have have a working widget now (sort of). However, my understanding of what a widget is really for not quite right. 

I'm trying to send a widget a object of options to init a chart from those options, be able to edit it and be able to drag and drop the whole widget anywhere on the screen.

Is this doable using a widget?

I think I need to obtain more experience with this framework.